# Как можно массив байтов разбить на другие массивы с нулём как разделителем?

Tags: java, массивы, строки, split, байты

Как можно массив байтов разделить на другие массивы между нулём, как это делает метод `split` со строками?

К примеру:

```
{1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5}
```

превратить в

```
{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4, 5}}
```

Comment: пройтись циклом и добавить в новый массив все элементы, кроме 0

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача, на самом деле, весьма интересная и понятная. Ниже моё решение, а ещё ниже - объяснение:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5,0,0,0,0,0};
    int[] b = fuse(a);

    int blocks=0;
    int[] size=new int[b.length];
    for (int i = 0; i <b.length-1 ; i++) {
        int mass=0;
        for (int j = i; j < b.length; j++) {
            if(b[j]==0){
                i=j;
                break;
            }
            mass++;
        }
        size[blocks]=mass;
        blocks++;
    }

    int cursor=0;
    int[][] out=new int[blocks][];
    for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
        out[i]=Arrays.copyOfRange(b,cursor,cursor+size[i]);
        cursor+=size[i]+1;
    }

    write(out);
}

private static void write(int[][] out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(i+": ");
        for (int j = 0; j < out[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(out[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static int[] fuse(int[] a) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (!(a[i-1]==a[i]&&a[i]==0)) {
            list.add(a[i]);
        }
    }
    if(list.get(list.size()-1)==0)
        list.remove(list.size()-1);

    int[] b=new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        b[i]=list.get(i);
    }

    return b;
}
```

Функция `fuse()` удаляет повторяющиеся и крайние нули.

```
private static int[] fuse(int[] a) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (!(a[i-1]==a[i]&&a[i]==0)) {
            list.add(a[i]);
        }
    }
    if(list.get(list.size()-1)==0)
        list.remove(list.size()-1);

    int[] b=new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        b[i]=list.get(i);
    }

    return b;
}
```

Блок кода, отвечающий за вычисления размеров выходного массива, где:

`blocks` - количество строк, `size[blocks]` - количество столбцов в строке

```
int blocks=0;
    int[] size=new int[b.length];
    for (int i = 0; i <b.length-1 ; i++) {
        int mass=0;
        for (int j = i; j < b.length; j++) {
            if(b[j]==0){
                i=j;
                break;
            }
            mass++;
        }
        size[blocks]=mass;
        blocks++;
    }
```

И, конечно, самое интересное - запись. Мы создаём переменную "курсор" `cursor`, которая будет помнить, откуда следует начинать копирование массива

```
int cursor=0;
int[][] out=new int[blocks][];
for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
    out[i]=Arrays.copyOfRange(b,cursor,cursor+size[i]);
    cursor+=size[i]+1;
}
```

Если будут вопросы - задавайте! Уверен, что что-нибудь, да забыл объяснить...

Answer (score 0):

```java
int[] arr1 = {1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5};
```

```java
// получаем строку из массива цифр
String str = Arrays.stream(arr1)
        // представляем каждую
        // цифру в виде строки
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        // объединяем в одну строку
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(str); // 10203045
```

```java
// делим строку на массив подстрок
// по символам разделителям "0"
String[] arr2 = str.split("0");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [1, 2, 3, 45]
```

```java
// получаем двумерный массив
// цифр из массива подстрок
int[][] arr3 = Arrays.stream(arr2)
        // выкидываем пустые подстроки
        .filter(st -> !st.isEmpty())
        // из каждой подстроки
        // получаем массив цифр
        .map(st -> st.codePoints()
                .mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray())
        // массивы собираем
        // в двумерный масив
        .toArray(int[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr3)); // [[1], [2], [3], [4, 5]]
```

---

См. [Откуда берётся элемент null при использовании команды toArray в java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/891240/420361)