# Откуда берётся элемент null при использовании команды toArray в java?

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции

Есть код:

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(0);
list.add(1);
list.add(2);

Integer[] array = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
list.toArray(array);

for (Integer x : array) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", x);
}
```

Output: `0 1 2 null 9`

**Вопрос**: откуда `null` в третьем элементе? Ведь

```java
System.out.println(list.get(3)); //Index Out of bounds exception;
```

---

**UPDATE:** из принятого ответа ясно, что это сделано для разметки. Если кто-нибудь даст ответ, для чего используется такая разметка, получит, как минимум +1 к репе.

Comment: array и arraylist должны быть одинакового размера

Comment: UPDATE: из принятого ответа ясно, что это сделано для разметки. Если кто-нибудь даст ответ, для чего используется такая разметка, получит, как минимум +1 к репе.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1218383/420361 - наверное, для восьмеричных систем исчисления подходит такой способ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из документации [`List.toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-):

> If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare (i.e., the array has more elements than the list), the element in the array immediately following the end of the list is set to null. (This is useful in determining the length of the list only if the caller knows that the list does not contain any null elements.)

> *Если список помещается в переданный массив целиком и еще остается место (т.е. когда в массиве больше элементов чем в списке), элементу массива, который следует после конца списка задается значение null. (Это полезно при определеннии длины списка если при вызове метода известно, что список не содержит null).*

В массиве `array` пять элементов, в списке — 3. Метод `toArray` записывает список в первые три элемента массива, четвертый отмечает как null, а остальные (пятый) не трогает.

Comment: Я готов принять ваш ответ, можете хоть намекнуть, на кой чёрт так сделано? Чтобы меня запутать или для более важных задач? Что означает эта магическая фраза: _Это полезно при определеннии длины списка если при вызове метода известно, что список не содержит null_

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Если честно не знаю. Сам полез в доки и был удивлен. Магическая фраза означает, что после вызова `toArray` по массиву можно определить до какого места в него был записан список. Возможно кто-то когда-то использовал массив повторно и это было полезно.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin В принципе можете не закрывать вопрос, а дополнить его вопросом вида: «Зачем нужно такое поведение?». Вдруг кто-нибудь предложит пример полезного использования.

Comment: Да ладно, я тоже в  доках не нашёл. Значит что-то не очевидное. Узнаете (или я узнаю) отредактируем ваш ответ.

Comment: Имхо, ничего полезного в этом нет, потому что мой исходный arraylist мог и так содержать `null`ы. Разработчики, похоже попытались сделать разметку. Вышло убого.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Поведение действительно странное. Если вызвать `toArray` для пустого списка, то метод просто затрет первый элемент. Мораль здесь такова: нужно передавать в `toArray` либо пустой массив, либо массив размера `list.size()`.

Comment: такое поведение актуально для concurrent коллекций.

Comment: @zRrr А можете пример привести или рассказать поподробнее как это помогает concurrent коллекциям?

Comment: нет гарантии, что `size()` вернет столько элементов, сколько положит `toArray(..)`. Обычно в таких ситуациях метод возвращает количество элементов (напр. [`BlockingQueue::drainTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo(java.util.Collection)), но у `toArray(..)` место занято.